# Can we pass an object as an argument in object call?

Tags: php

I read somewhere

> The parameter of a constructor can be of any type except that of the class to which it belongs.

So

```
$obj = new class_name(new class_name());
```

is this permitted in PHP?

Comment: 1) Have you tested it? 2) Have you thought about it?

Comment: @Rizier123 yes https://3v4l.org/BkVh8

Comment: You get the warning because the "inner" `new A` has no parameter. https://3v4l.org/lOWhn or https://3v4l.org/Z8flQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well to find out, why don't we just run the code and go through step by step what happens, shall we?

So if the class takes an argument to the constructor, this means it would have to look something like this:

```
class A {
    public function __construct($parameter){

    }
}
```

Now we create an instance of it:

```
$o = new A(new A);
```

But the argument needs also an instance:

```
$o = new A(new A(new A));
```

But the argument needs also an instance:

```
$o = new A(new A(new A(new A)));
```

But the argument needs also an instance:

```
$o = new A(new A(new A(new A(new A))));
```

But the argument needs also an instance:

```
$o = new A(new A(new A(new A(new A(new A)))));
```

But the argument needs also an instance:

```
$o = new A(new A(new A(new A(new A(new A(new A))))));
```

...wait now I'm lost.

---

And to the rescue comes ["default argument values"](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default)! As VolkerK already pointed out in the comments it is not impossible, you just have to make sure you end the chain somewhere somehow. And that somehow is with default values, e.g.

```
class A {
    public function __construct($parameter = NULL){

    }
}
```

So with the default value the chain will end then, when you don't pass another instance to the constructor and it will take the default value, which will be `NULL` here.

Comment: default parameter values to the rescue ;-)

Comment: Well this will go infinity

Comment: @Exception You got the ["Aha effect"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_effect).

Comment: But does it demonstrate that the answer is still "yes"?

Comment: @Exception As VolkerK already commented you still can do it as long as you make an end, e.g.with a default parameter as he really nicely showed here: https://3v4l.org/Z8flQ

Comment: and to know how many objects are created we are using count right?

Comment: @Exception The easiest way to do this is probably using a static property and increment that each time you get a class instance in the constructor.

Comment: @Exception *But the argument needs also an instance:*, sorry just got a bit lost while trying some code. You're welcome :P